How can I remove host from inventory file?
Here is my /etc/ansible/inventory
[applications]
SVC1 ansible_host=10.252.20.208
SVC2 ansible_host=10.252.20.209

Is there any ansible module to remove or comment host SVC1 in inventory file?
Expected /etc/ansible/inventory
[applications]
# SVC1 ansible_host=10.252.20.208
SVC2 ansible_host=10.252.20.209

Context: I have an application running in SVC1 host, whenever it is uninstalled (using my ansible scripts), I want to remove/comment entry related to that application from inventory file.
What I tried without success:
---
- name: update inventory
  hosts: all
  run_once: true
  tasks:
    - name: Remove the peer configuration for 10.128.0.11/32
      community.general.ini_file:
        path: /etc/ansible/inventory
        section: applications 
        option: SVC1
        state: absent
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true


what's reason behind downvote?

The inventory file is mentioned for which host can be managed, not for the content / configuration of the host itself. var files, group var files, facts, custom facts, etc. are mentioned for the configuration content of the hosts. This means in my opinion "whenever it is uninstalled (using my ansible scripts), I want to remove/comment entry related to that application from inventory file.", the Use Case should be addressed in a different way (... other files). There is absolute no need to edit / modify the inventory file itself for this case.

There are no specific modules to edit the inventory files.
In most of the cases you're not supposed to edit your static inventory file by Ansible itself. The general idea is that you bring your machines into the state defined by your inventory. While there still are use cases where your approach would be valid, it's prone to a simple issue - if you uninstall the application from all your hosts, your playbook will not be able to function anymore.
Similarly to the backward compatibility pattern, your task could be solved the other way around - instead of removing the hosts where the app should be uninstalled from, consider adding them to a separate group:
[applications]
SVC2 ansible_host=10.252.20.209

[applications_uninstall]
SVC1 ansible_host=10.252.20.208

This way you'll be able to run both installation and uninstallation workflows in an idempotent manner as many times as you need. To decommission your application completely, just move all the hosts from the application group to application_uninstall, run the playbook(s), and that's it.
The remaining use cases are actually way more complex (like implementing GitOps and/or synchronizing the state of a dynamically changing system with the repository) and INI format doesn't look suitable for them.

Just my opinion, I consider that if an application should be or is installed on a Remote System as a (Custom) Fact which could even be maintained in var files ...

Yes, that's also an option (maybe even a better one - depending on the details of the use case).
